# How do I properly set the Datetimeindex for a Pandas datetime object in a dataframe?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
    lat         lng         alt days              date        time
0   40.003834   116.321462  211 39745.175405      2008-10-24  04:12:35
1   40.003783   116.321431  201 39745.175463  2008-10-24      04:12:40
2   40.003690   116.321429  203 39745.175521      2008-10-24      04:12:45
3   40.003589   116.321427  194 39745.175579      2008-10-24      04:12:50
4   40.003522   116.321412  190 39745.175637      2008-10-24      04:12:55
5   40.003509   116.321484  188 39745.175694      2008-10-24      04:13:00
```

For which I am trying to convert the df['date'] and df['time'] columns into a datetime.  I can do:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']+df['time'])
df = df.set_index(['Datetime'])
del df['date']
del df['time']
```

And I get:

```
                    lat         lng         alt days
Datetime                            
2008-10-2404:12:35  40.003834   116.321462  211 39745.175405    
2008-10-2404:12:40  40.003783   116.321431  201 39745.175463
2008-10-2404:12:45  40.003690   116.321429  203 39745.175521    
2008-10-2404:12:50  40.003589   116.321427  194 39745.175579    
2008-10-2404:12:55  40.003522   116.321412  190 39745.175637
```

But then if I try:

```
df.between_time(time(1),time(22,59,59))['lng'].std()
```

I get an error - 'TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex'

So, I've also tried setting the DatetimeIndex:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']+df['time'])
#df = df.set_index(['Datetime'])
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Datetime']))
del df['date']
del df['time']
```

And this throws an error also - 'DateParseError: unknown string format'

How do I create the datetime column and DatetimeIndex correctly so that df.between_time() works right?

Comment: The 'DateParseError: unknown string format' is that it cannot figure out the "2008-10-2404:12:35" format since the 'DD' and 'HH' are adjacent.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

To simplify [Kirubaharan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27032197/10470171) a bit:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
df = df.set_index('Datetime')
```

And to get rid of unwanted columns (as OP did but did not specify per se in the question):

```
df = df.drop(['date','time'], axis=1)
```

Comment: So the trick here is adding a space between the date and time and then the `pd.to_datetime()` Does The Right Thing with the resultant strings?

Answer (score 82):

You are not creating datetime index properly,

```
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'], format=format)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Datetime']))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to set `inplace=True`. This way it returns the same `df`

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"] + " " + df["time"], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df.set_index(["datetime"], inplace=True)
```

Comment: if `inplace=True`, does it really return anything? can we simply remove the assignment operator and just use the right-hand-side?

Comment: @MJK In place prevents you from creating df object by performing the operation on the same df. To use the assignment on the right, you'd have to type in the operation as the first argument to `df.set_index`, It is cleaner to use the assignment operator first.

Answer (score 1):

This worked best for me:

```
format = '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S'
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['time'].astype("string"), format=format)
```

In some cases Python treats `df['date']` as column of integers.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with setting a column formatted as YYYY-MM-DD as a date time index column in a data frame I needed for time series forecasting. This is how I solved it for a dateframe where I wanted "dateCol" to be the datetime index:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(self.df[dateCol])
self.df = self.df.set_index(idx)
```

Then to drop the column so it's not duplicated in the dataframe

```
self.df = self.df.drop(dateCol, axis=1)
```