# Pandas between_time keeps giving index error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm new to programming and I'm building a first python project.
I'm trying to drop the rows in a pandas dataframe between 22:00 and 06:00.
I'm trying to use the between_time function but it keeps giving the error:
Index must be DatetimeIndex
But I already set the index to a datetime field:

```
google_fit_df.set_index(['Begintijd'], drop=False)
```

[Datatype 'Begintijd']

[image: 1]

[Output]

[image: 2]

```
google_fit_df.between_time('22:00','24:00')
```

And then i get the following error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 google_fit_df.between_time('22:00','24:00')
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
> between_time(self, start_time, end_time, include_start, include_end,
> axis)    7974         index = self._get_axis(axis)    7975         if
> not isinstance(index, DatetimeIndex):
> -> 7976             raise TypeError("Index must be DatetimeIndex")    7977     7978         indexer = index.indexer_between_time(
>
> TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex

Hope anyone can tell me what i'm doing wrong here :)
Thanks!

Comment: After you set the index, is it actually recognized as a DatetimeIntex?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different format just like
Kirubaharan J posted in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27032197/14481779

```
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
df['Begintijd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Begintijd'], format=format)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Begintijd']))
```

Comment: That doesn't work, i think thats because the original format pf the field is 00:15:00.000+01:00. When i use pd.to_datetime it adds 01-01-1900 to the field. If i change the format it returns a ValueError
ValueError: time data 00:00:00.000+01:00 doesn't match format specified