# Python - Pandas - Plot Data frame without headers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to use the .plot() function in pandas to plot data into a line graph.

The data sorted by date with 48 rows after each date. Sample below:

```
                       1         2  ...        46        47        48
18  2018-02-19  1.317956  1.192840  ...  1.959250  1.782985  1.418093
19  2018-02-20  1.356267  1.192248  ...  2.123432  1.760629  1.569340
20  2018-02-21  1.417181  1.288694  ...  2.086715  1.823581  1.612062
21  2018-02-22  1.431536  1.279514  ...  2.201972  1.878109  1.694159
```

etc until row 346.

I tried the below but .plot does not seem to take positional arguments:

```
df.plot(x=df.iloc[0:346,0],y=[0:346,1:49]
```

How would I go about plotting my rows by date (the 1st column) on a line graph and can I expand this to include multiple axis?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, some of which are directly through the pandas dataframe. However, given your sample plotting line, I think the easiest might be to just use matplotlib directly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df.iloc[0:346,0],df.iloc[0:346,1:49])
```

For multiple axes you can add a few lines to make subplots. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(df.iloc[0:346,0],df.iloc[0:346,1:10],ax=ax1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(df.iloc[0:346,0],df.iloc[0:346,20:30],ax=ax2)
```

You can also do this using the pandas `plot()` function that you were trying to use - it also takes an `ax` argument the same way as above, where you can provide the axis on which to plot. If you want to stick to pandas, I think you'd be best off setting the index to be a datetime index (see this link as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27051371/12133280) and then using `df.plot('column_name',ax=ax1)`. The x axis will be the index, which you would have set to be the date.

Comment: When I run this I unfortunately get the error:

TypeError: plot got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'. 

I have imported all dependences so this is confusing.

Comment: Sorry you're right. I edited it. The first two arguments are x and y, but it doesn't work to say x= and y=. Hopefully it works now.